# Completed Xquery for multiple for loops

Tags: eclipse, xquery, oracle-service-bus

I have the input request like below

```
<Input>
<BusinessObjects>
      <BusinessObject>
        <BusinessIdentifiers>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>BuCode</BKey>
            <BValue>CDC</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>BuType</BKey>
            <BValue>123</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>CsmNo</BKey>
            <BValue>857895</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
        </BusinessIdentifiers>
       </BusinessObject>
      <BusinessObject>
        <BusinessIdentifiers>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>BuCode</BKey>
            <BValue>CDC</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>BuType</BKey>
            <BValue>123</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
          <BusinessIdentifier>
            <BKey>CsmNo</BKey>
            <BValue>34567</BValue>
          </BusinessIdentifier>
        </BusinessIdentifiers>
        </BusinessObject>      
    </BusinessObjects>
    </Input>
```

i need to form an output like below schema

```
<Output>
<BusinessObject>
<BIKey></BIKey>
<BKey></BIKey>
<Bvalue></Bvalue>
<BOID></BOID>
</BusinessObject>
</Output>
```

For the above payload
The output should be

```
<Output>
<BusinessObjects>
<BusinessObject>
<BIKey>CDC:123:857895|CDC:123:34567</BIKey>
<BKey>BUCode</BKey>
<Bvalue>CDC</Bvalue>
<BOID>CDC:123:857895</BOID>
</BusinessObject>
<BusinessObject>
<BIKey>CDC:123:857895|CDC:123:34567</BIKey>
<BKey>BUtype</BKey>
<Bvalue>123</Bvalue>
<BOID>CDC:123:857895</BOID>
</BusinessObject>
<BusinessObject>
<BIKey>CDC:123:857895|CDC:123:34567</BIKey>
<BKey>CSMNo</BKey>
<Bvalue>857895</Bvalue>
<BOID>CDC:123:857895</BOID>
</BusinessObject>
<BusinessObject>
<BIKey>CDC:123:857895|CDC:123:34567</BIKey>
<BKey>BUCode</BKey>
<Bvalue>CDC</Bvalue>
<BOID>CDC:123:34567</BOID>
</BusinessObject>
<BusinessObject>
<BIKey>CDC:123:857895|CDC:123:34567</BIKey>
<BKey>BUtype</BKey>
<Bvalue>123</Bvalue>
<BOID>CDC:123:34567</BOID>
</BusinessObject>
<BusinessObject>
<BIKey>CDC:123:857895|CDC:123:34567</BIKey>
<BKey>CSMNo</BKey>
<Bvalue>857895</Bvalue>
<BOID>CDC:123:34567</BOID>
</BusinessObject>
</BusinessObjects>
</Output>
```

i have tried below Xquery to get the same but ended up with errors or not meeting the requiremnt

```
<Ouput>
<BusinessObjects>
{
for $bi in Input/BusinessObjects/BusinessObject/BusinessIdentifiers/BusinessIdentifier
return
<BIKey>
    {
        string-join(
            for $bo in Input/BusinessObjects/BusinessObject return string-join($bo/BusinessIdentifiers/BusinessIdentifier/BValue, '|'),
            ':'
        )
    }
    </BIKey>
    <BKey>data {$bi/Bkey}</BKey>
    <Bvalue>data {$bi/Bvalue}</Bvalue>
    for $bo in Input/BusinessObjects/BusinessObject return <BOID>{string-join($bo//BValue, ':')}<BOID>

}
</BusinessObjects>
</Ouput>
```

the description for the output fields as follows
BIKey-->it has formed with all the Bvalues of 'Business Identifier' concatenated with ':'  and then for each businessobject it is separed with '|'
Bkey-->Straight mapping with bkey
Bvalue-->Straight mapping with Bvalue
BOID--> it has to formed for each businessobject, need to concatenate the values Bvalues of Business Identifiers with ':'
Any suggestions, i believe that i have to two complex loops in here, but not able to crack it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the query

```
<Output>
    <BusinessObjects>
        {
            //BusinessIdentifier 
            ! 
            <BusinessObject>
                <BIKey>{string-join(ancestor::BusinessObjects/BusinessObject!string-join(.//BValue, ':'), '|')}</BIKey>
                {
                    BKey, 
                    BValue
                }
                <BOID>{ancestor::BusinessObject!string-join(.//BValue, ':')}</BOID>
            </BusinessObject>
        }
    </BusinessObjects>
</Output>
```

at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5g I get the result

```
<Output>
   <BusinessObjects>
      <BusinessObject>
         <BIKey>CDC:123:857895|CDC:123:34567</BIKey>
         <BKey>BuCode</BKey>
         <BValue>CDC</BValue>
         <BOID>CDC:123:857895</BOID>
      </BusinessObject>
      <BusinessObject>
         <BIKey>CDC:123:857895|CDC:123:34567</BIKey>
         <BKey>BuType</BKey>
         <BValue>123</BValue>
         <BOID>CDC:123:857895</BOID>
      </BusinessObject>
      <BusinessObject>
         <BIKey>CDC:123:857895|CDC:123:34567</BIKey>
         <BKey>CsmNo</BKey>
         <BValue>857895</BValue>
         <BOID>CDC:123:857895</BOID>
      </BusinessObject>
      <BusinessObject>
         <BIKey>CDC:123:857895|CDC:123:34567</BIKey>
         <BKey>BuCode</BKey>
         <BValue>CDC</BValue>
         <BOID>CDC:123:34567</BOID>
      </BusinessObject>
      <BusinessObject>
         <BIKey>CDC:123:857895|CDC:123:34567</BIKey>
         <BKey>BuType</BKey>
         <BValue>123</BValue>
         <BOID>CDC:123:34567</BOID>
      </BusinessObject>
      <BusinessObject>
         <BIKey>CDC:123:857895|CDC:123:34567</BIKey>
         <BKey>CsmNo</BKey>
         <BValue>34567</BValue>
         <BOID>CDC:123:34567</BOID>
      </BusinessObject>
   </BusinessObjects>
</Output>
```

In XQuery 1 you don't have the `!` simple map operator but you should be able to use `for .. return` instead, see https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5g/1 with

```
<Output>
    <BusinessObjects>
        {
            for $bi in //BusinessIdentifier 
            return  
            <BusinessObject>
                <BIKey>{string-join($bi/ancestor::BusinessObjects/BusinessObject/string-join(.//BValue, ':'), '|')}</BIKey>
                {
                    $bi/BKey, 
                    $bi/BValue
                }
                <BOID>{$bi/ancestor::BusinessObject/string-join(.//BValue, ':')}</BOID>
            </BusinessObject>
        }
    </BusinessObjects>
</Output>
```

or simple steps constructing a new element, see https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn5g/2 with

```
<Output>
    <BusinessObjects>
        {
            //BusinessIdentifier/
            <BusinessObject>
                <BIKey>{string-join(ancestor::BusinessObjects/BusinessObject/string-join(.//BValue, ':'), '|')}</BIKey>
                {
                    BKey, 
                    BValue
                }
                <BOID>{ancestor::BusinessObject/string-join(.//BValue, ':')}</BOID>
            </BusinessObject>
        }
    </BusinessObjects>
</Output>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, but just want to make sure that i am using Xquery version of 1.0. Will 'ancestor' works in this version?

Comment: See the edit where I have tried to use XQuery 1 alternatives like `for .. return` or a step with an element constructor instead of the `!` map operator. As for `ancestor`, for sure that is supported in XQuery 1 as specified, I can't tell whether any of the often rather restricted or primitive XQuery support attempts in various SQL databases have that. Anyway, if you target a certain version or certain environment, add tags for them to your question to make sure people trying to answer know your restrictions.

Comment: Hi Martin, i am trying to embedd this code into my actual code but i ended up like below 
{err}XP0004 [{bea-err}XP0004b]: Found type mismatch in expression. Only empty sequence satisfies type checking rules. Expected type: node*. Actual type: {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string*. Either the XQuery is invalid or it contains custom XQuery functions. Try using the web test console to test this XQuery

Any Idea on this?

Comment: Well, if your environment says "Try using the web test console to test this XQuery" then do that, hopefully it gives you a detailed error message with details about which part of the query causes the error. Or as I said, edit your question and tag it with details of the XQuery processor/enviroment you use, then hopefully someone with expertise on the XQuery dialect or version you have available can help with some fitting code. You could also try rewriting stuff like `$bi/ancestor::BusinessObject/string-join(.//BValue, ':')` as `for $bo in $bi return string-join($bo//Value, ':')`.

Comment: Hi Martin, i am not able to deploy to the server until i have clear the error from eclipse. Any thoughts how to prcoeed with eclipse? BTW, i am using the Xquery transfomration in an OSB Project.

Comment: @sivakumarkala, hopefully someone else can help, in my view my suggestion should do with XQuery as specified, I don't know about the two tags you have added, let's hope someone else sees your question and can help solving it.

Comment: @ Martin Honnen, Will it be possbile to get the above requirement by not using 'ancestor'?

Comment: Sorry, I am used to solve problems of XSLT/XPath/XQuery with support for all axes including the `ancestor` one, I don't have any interest in trying to rewrite code to work with an unknown environment with restricted features, so hopefully someone else knowing OSB/Eclipse and its "XQuery" support or lack of it can help further.